# Can fineuploader be disabled yet still render the screen elements?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Is it possible to disable the fine-uploader upload functionality, but still have fine-uploader render the various divs and input fields etc?

I have a series of uploader buttons, some of which are disabled (based on user prefs etc). I still want the buttons to render, but I want to disable the actual upload functionality.

Edit: Im using the jQuery version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent users from uploading files a number of different ways.  One way is to simply allow them to drop/submit/select files, but reject them in an `onSubmit`, `onValidateBatch`, or `onValidate` [callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/callbacks.html) handler:

```
// Change this value to true on-demand to ensure 
// all future submitted files are rejected.
var preventUploads = false;

var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('uploadContainer'),
    request: {
        endpoint: '/my/endpoint'
    },
    callbacks: {
        onValidateBatch: function(fileOrBlobDataArray) {
            if (preventUploads) {
                // TODO Let the user know why the file is being rejected

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
)};
```

Please note that I have used the no-dependency version of Fine Uploader in my examples. If you are in fact using the jQuery plug-in version of Fine Uploader, you will need to have a look at the documentation or update your question with the proper tags so I can update my code.

Comment: Is there no general way to disable uploads while using the jQuery version?

Comment: @vsync Yes, via the itemLimit option.  Also, please don't post the same question in multiple places.